# How to show overflow with expanded SearchView?

Tags: android, searchview

So I have an expanded `SearchView` inside `ActionBar` using following code.

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); //expand searchview
```

but this makes the overflow menu item disappear. How to show them on the right side of expanded `SearchView`?

[image]

**menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Search"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"`and also

remove `searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);`
and add this

```
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
     SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
      MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(searchItem);
```